# Thread Safe way to access SQL CE Database

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-7, sql-server-ce

Background:

In my windows phone project. I use local SQL CE database to store date. The create the database tables using LINQ to SQL programmatically.

This database is accessed through various datacontext instances in couple of threads.

Here's the issue:

I give an option to the user of my app to erase all the data and logout. When the user selects this, I delete the database using the datacontext's DeleteDatabase method. But, I always receive the error that the database is being used by another process, hence cannot delete.

Any nudges in the right direction will make my day.

Comment: When you call Delete DB do you have any connections still open? It is most likly your process that has access to the DB and not something else.

Comment: Well I closed all the connections i know could be open. Is there any way to get the processes that are using the database and kill them?

Comment: Do you wrap all instances of the DataContext in using statements and/or Dispose of them?

Comment: @ErikEj Thanks for pointing that  out. I overlooked one instance where I wasn't using the 'using' statement. Changing that solved the problem. Like I said you made my day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andy as mentioned above (to be honest they beat me) the problem was accessing the database when another process still had the connection opened. Basically it can be easily fixed by placing any code you run against the database inside of a using block like so:

```
using (MyDataContext db = new MyDataContext("isostore:/MyData.sdf"))
{
    //Run database logic here
}
```

I guess in a sense it makes perfect sense for the error. Same thing happens with open files in WP7.

For more information and an example check out this [page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202860%28v=VS.92%29.aspx).

Comment: Hi I've tried this way i mean i used using block everywhere but still when I'm trying to delete database it gives me error.