# Deleting local database sdf file from isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I am trying to delete my local database file which is 'transferDB.sdf' via this code.

```
    PrideDataContext db = new PrideDataContext(App.DBConnectionString);

                if (db.DatabaseExists())
                {
                    //db.Dispose();
                   db.DeleteDatabase();
                }
```

but when I try to run this code it gives me following exception.

$exception  {System.IO.IOException: The process cannot access the file 'C:\Data\Users\DefApps\AppData{AF715F29-8BFC-48DE-AD88-E71D8F37BC26}\local\transferDB.sdf' because it is being used by another process.

Why is is trying to delete a file in my local data folder instead of in the real device that I am testing?

Pretty confused. Can somebody help me here? ( I think its referring to one of my emulator's temporary SDF file instead of the Device's one)

Comment: You have created a database from your application code? Or added a database to your project?

Comment: I create it in App.xaml.cs constructor, like this,

            DBConnectionString = "Data Source=isostore:/transferDB.sdf";
            using (PrideDataContext db = new PrideDataContext(DBConnectionString))
            {
                if (!db.DatabaseExists())
                {
                    db.CreateDatabase();

                }
            }

Comment: I think this post and round it will help you 
[Thread Safe way to access SQL CE Database][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9195913/thread-safe-way-to-access-sql-ce-database

Comment: Your device also has drive with letter *C:* and it probably referrs to right file. I suspect that problem is because you haven't disposed/closed some resources connected with file and thus it can't be deleted.